# Obtain the JsonNode from a Promise[JsonNode] in Java and return that value

Tags: java, playframework, callback, promise

I'm writing a Play 2.3.2 application in Java.

In my application I make a call to a method of an other module, written in Scala.

This method returns a Json response and I try to obtain that using WS.

This is my method implementation:

```
public static JsonNode getCorrelationData() {
        WSRequestHolder holder = WS.url(ConfigFactory.load().getString("host") + "/recommendation/correlation");
        Promise<JsonNode> jsonPromise = holder.get().map(
                new Function<WSResponse, JsonNode>() {
                    public JsonNode apply(WSResponse response) {
                        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
                            Logger.error("Error on get correlation data");
                            Logger.error("Response status code: " + response.getStatus());
                            Logger.error("Response status text: " + response.getStatusText());
                        }

                        return response.asJson();
                    }
                });



        //here I want to obtain the JsonNode inside the jsonPromise object, and return it.
    }
```

But the problem is that the callback returns a Promise, and my method need to return a JsonNode.

How can I obtain the JsonNode inside the Promise?? I can'f find any solution to my problem.

In Scala I know that I can use the flatMap on a Future[T].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your method performs an asynchronous operation and thus should not return a `JsonNode` but rather a `Promise<JsonNode>`.

Conceptually - this makes sense - your method does not immediately fetch the data - rather it dispatches a task relating to the said data that will finish some time in the future. You can access the response by unwrapping the promise. You can return the `Promise<JsonNode>` and then call `.map` on it at the caller site to unwrap the value.

You can also call `.get()` on the promise which would force the data to wait for the result (that is - returning `jsonPromise.get()` but that negates the benefit of using promises to begin with. Note that `get()` here is different from the `get()` on holder which is fine since it just returns the promise.

Comment: I'll reinforce what Benjamin's saying here. If you can, try to keep your method returning a `Promise<JsonNode>` but change your caller to handle a `Promise`. Do *not* use `get()`. Use all the non-blocking `Promise` methods (`map`, `flatmap`, etc) to access your data in a non-blocking way. If this is a Play app, then you should be able to write all your code in a non-blocking way because the framework allows your controllers to return a `Promise<Result>`.

Answer (score 1):

Return promise of result instead:

```
public static Promise<Result> getPromise() {
    WSRequestHolder url = WS.url("url");
    Promise<Result> promise = url.get().map((r) -> {
        if (r.getStatus() == 200) {
            return ok(r.asJson());
        } else {
            return badRequest("Bad request");
        }
    });
    return promise;
}
```

Comment: It's not a controller method, I can return a Promise<JsonNode>, but Promise<Result> is wrong for my use.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed it is controller method, because it is static.

Comment: I fail to see how this is any different from my answer from 4 years ago - only explaining less and using Java 8 syntax.

Comment: You fail to see because you are member for 2 years and 6 months.

Comment: @MonCalamari that was an honest question - I didn't downvote you or  anything. I'm genuinely wondering what you thought was lacking in my answer that you decided to add yours. I'm asking _you_ for criticism. I don't understand how "2 years membership" explains it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I assumed OP's `java` method was a controller method thus returning promise of result would be best choice. My assumption was wrong, your answer is correct, `upvoted`.